# How can I prove that we have $∠(r(u), r(v)) = ∠(u, v)$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

How can I prove in geometry that for any $r \in O^+(\mathbb{E})$ we have $∠(r(u), r(v)) = ∠(u, v)$? And what can I say about the case where $r$ is a reflection? Where we write  $O^+(\mathbb{E})$ for the orientation preserving elements of $O(\mathbb{E})$ and $\mathbb{E}$ is a two-dimensional vector space with inner product with a fixed orientation. The group of rotations $O^+(\mathbb{E})$ is generated by pairs of
reflections in lines through the origin.

Any help or tip would be grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The linear transformation $r$ preserves the norm and the inner product, so by the definition of angle between vectors, they will be also preserved.

Comment: Is it possible that $r \in SO(\mathbb{E})$ and $r$ is a reflection?

Comment: I was already thinking of applying the norm and inner product. Not really sure how to start though

Answer (score 0):

Rephrasing Berci's comment/NOT an answer.

It depends on your definition. Normally orthogonal transformation is defined as the inner product (and hence norm) preserving linear map. In that case, there is nothing to prove.

If you define orthogonal transformations as the linear transformations $T$ on $E$ (finite-dimensional) such that $TT^{*}=I,$ then it is also clear from the definition. It would be great if you could write your definition of $SO(\mathbb{E}).$ In that case, people would be able to help you.

NB: If $r$ is a reflection, then $r \in O(\mathbb{E})$ but $r \notin SO(\mathbb{E}).$

Comment: I have rephrased the question

Comment: If $r$ is a reflection (non-orientation preserving), the equality is still true.

Comment: I have difficulties proving the equality using inner product and norms

Comment: The elements of $O(\mathbb{E})$ preserves the inner product.

Comment: $\mathbb{E}$ is a two-dimensional vector space with inner product with a fixed orientation

Comment: What is the def of  $O(\mathbb{E})$ ?

Comment: the group of rotations $O^+(\mathbb{E})$ is generated by pairs of
reflections in lines through the origin.